# How can I re-render current page in Rails without using redirect_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I need to be able to do

```
render 'current page', :notice => 'message'
```

The notice is lost when using `redirect_to`, probably because I'm doing this in active-admin. But it works for `render`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flash` in this scenario, which saves key-value pairs across web requests:

```
flash[:notice] => 'message'

redirect_to some_url
```

Then inside your view for the URL you've redirected to:

```
<h1><%= flash[:notice] %></h1>
```

Additional reference: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html